# What's wrong with django queryset? I get different answer when access the same indice

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I found that the objects could be duplicate in a queryset. However, when I try to access each of the object and do nothing, it changes and seems to be right.
[Here are the commands I have typed into the shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFNO9.png)

At first I gained a queryset orderby the field `'receiveTime'`. Then it seems that `ds[1996]` equals to `ds[1997]`. And I try to use the loop:

```
for d in ds:
    pass
```

Then the `ds[1996]` isn't equal to `ds[1997]`, but what have I done?

Maybe it is a feature of the lazy search?

plus 1:I have reproduced it just now. I didn't do any inserting or deleting just now.
[These are the commands I just typed into the shell.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wfiH.png)

plus 2:I have seen the raw sql queries when I call the `ds[0]` and `ds[1]` which I have shown in the picture 2. The sql queries are correct but the answer seems to be wrong. I think maybe the reason is that the sorting parameter `receiveTime` of two objects are the same, which lead to the disorder of the objects?
[Here are the raw sql queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFFuD.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `order_by("receive_time")` with `order_by("receive_time", "id")`. PostgreSQL [uses qsort](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/qsort_8c_source.html) which is an unstable sort. Given only `receive_time`, if values are the same, the order is not guaranteed.
2. [Don't post code or logs in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Ever.

Comment: Thanks for answering! But I'm pretty sure that the 'id' field is unique, and you can see not only the id is same, the result of 'ds[1996]==ds[1997]' is true. The database is postgresql. And I think when I was doing those queries, I didn't insert or delete the rows.......I have typed 'ds.count()' before and after the 'for' loop, the answer is equal. The worst thing is that I can't reappear the BUG now......whatever, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @nslam When you use `ds[1996]==ds[1997]` [django compares the ids](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#comparing-objects). As I mentioned, enable the logging. If you can't reproduce it, 99% something else was inserting/deleting rows. Also saying "thanks" is too verbose here, there are upvote/downvote/accept for it.

Comment: I have seen the raw sql queries and they are right which you can find in the image three. I think maybe the reason is that the sorting parameter of two objects are the same?